# Trying to Migrate in Development Mode

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables

I'm trying to figure out how I can get my environment set to development mode inside my Laravel application.

bootstrap/start.php

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

    'development' => array('blog.app'),
    'production' => array('')

));
```

Inside my routes file I have the following:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    dd(App::environment());
});
```

When I go to blog.app it says its set to production and I'm not sure why. The purpose of figuring out why its giving me production instead of development is because I am attempt to run the command "php artisan migrate" and its giving me the following.

```
My-iMac:blog my$ php artisan migrate
**************************************
*     Application In Production!     *
**************************************

Do you really wish to run this command?
```

So I need help understanding why its still saying application is in production mode when I'm attempting to be in development mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go inside your project directory. Then navigate to bootstrap/start.php.

Edit the local array specified in `$app->detectEnvironment` with your machine name.

Laravel will automatically check you machine name every time and know that it is a local environment and use the local configuration files instead. To use the local config files you can navigate to app/config/local and edit the files there. The files in app/config belong to the production environment. You can copy these files in the local folder and then edit them accordingly, for example you database configuration probably will differ on your local machine and the server.

You can simply edit the files in the config folders and Laravel will detect automatically the environment according to the array in the start.php and use the config files related to the machine on which you are working. You can also specify more environments and create their entries in the start.php file and then go and create a folder by the same name in the app/config folder and create config files for that environment in that folder.

Example: If you want to have two local environments you can edit you start.php file like so

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

    'local' => array('Machine1', 'Machine2'),.
    'local2' => array('Machine3', 'Machine4'),

));
```

And then navigate to the app/config folder and create two folders like local and local2 and have separate files for each of them. Now the machines with names Machine1 and Machine2 will automatically use config files present in local folder and Machine3 and Machine4 will use config files in local2 folder. This way Laravel provides great flexibility in setting environments.

For more information check out the **[Environments and Configuration](https://laracasts.com/lessons/environments-and-configuration)** Episode on Laracasts.

Answer (score 1):

You need to figure out your machine name. In order to do that, run this code anywhere:

```
echo gethostname();
exit;
```

More info about the function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostname.php

It will output your machine name, then you need to paste it in the 'development' array.